# For $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$ what function is in $L^p$ but not in $L^q$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$ and $-\infty\leq a<b\leq\infty$ be arbitrary. What specific functions satisfy $f\in L^p(a,b)$ and $f\notin L^q(a,b)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose a function $\psi(x)$ is in $L^n(a,b)$ if $\int_a^b|\psi(x)|^ndx$ converges. I also assume that $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$ then i guess 
$$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{(x-a)^\alpha}$$ 
will do for all $\alpha\in(q^{-1}, p^{-1})$

Comment: Why is it not in $L^q(a,b)$ ?

Comment: $\alpha q>1$ and hence the integral diverges. (The singularity will be huge)

Answer (score 1):

$L^{q}(X)\subseteq L^{p}(X)$ for $1\leq p\leq q\leq\infty$ for finite measure space $X$, this is by Holder's inequality.

For infinite measure, say, $L^{1}(1,\infty)$ and $L^{2}(1,\infty)$, consider $1/x\in L^{2}(1,\infty)$ and $1/x\notin L^{1}(1,\infty)$.

On the other hand, say, $L^{1}(0,1)$ and $L^{2}(0,1)$, consider $1/x^{1/2}\in L^{1}(0,1)$ and $1/x^{1/2}\notin L^{2}(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant the other way around. I changed the question

Comment: And though your example is a good one, I was wondering about general $p<q$ (the function would have to depend on p and q I guess)

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt Well, I guess you can generalize these examples for general $p,q$ quite easily, let $x^{\alpha}$ with a correctly chosen $\alpha$.