# Is there $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ such that given $\epsilon>0$, $f \not \in L^{p+\epsilon}(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Consider a measure space $(\Omega,\mu)$, where $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$.

It is classically known that if $p<q$, then $L^q(\Omega,\mu)\not\subset L^p(\Omega,\mu)$ (see [For $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$ what function is in $L^p$ but not in $L^q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716511/for-1-leq-pq-leq-infty-what-function-is-in-lp-but-not-in-lq/2716540)). The form of the argument on the link is that given $q>p\geq 1$, we construct a function $f \in L^p(\Omega,\mu)$ such that $f \not\in L^q(\Omega,\mu)$.

Is it possible to take one such function $f \in L^p(\Omega,\mu)$ such that $f \not \in L^{p+\epsilon}(\Omega,\mu)$ for every $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: With $\Omega = (0, 1)$, taking $f(x) = x^{\alpha}$ for appropriate $\alpha$ should work.

Comment: The thing is: if $\alpha=1$, then $f \not\in L^1(]0,1[)$. Therefore, we have to take $0<\alpha<1$ in order to assure that $f \in L^1(]0,1[)$. On the other hand: if $0<\alpha<1$, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f^{1+\epsilon} \in L^1(]0,1[)$.

Comment: For simplicity let $p=1$. Consider $f_n(x)=x^{-1+1/n} 1_{(0;1/n^2)}(x)$. Define $$g_n=f_n/(\Vert f_n\Vert_1).$$ Now define $$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n} g_n(x+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} 1/n^2).$$ As $\Vert g_n\Vert_1=1$, we get $f\in L^1$. On the other hand, given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n$ such that $g_n$ is not in $L^{1+\varepsilon}$. Thus, $f$ is not in $L^{1+\varepsilon}.$

Comment: Excelent. Thank you, @SeverinSchraven.

Comment: In my example, we can pick $\Omega=(0;\pi^2/6).$

Comment: I am not sure, we can say anything about general measure spaces. It seems hard to construct explicit examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition to find an $f\in\mathbb L^p$ but not in $\mathbb L^{p+\varepsilon}$ is that the involved measure space contains sets of arbitrarily small measure. See [here for the details](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion/66045#66045).